# Can I print on my HP printer?

Tags: printer

I have a network connected printer by HP. Can I print photos from my phone using it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Download the [HP AiO Remote](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=572f5ac8-b855-465c-9a52-aa46b1e3d1d9) app and print as much as you like.